# How to filter JSON in SphinxQL?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I have a JSON field with a simple numeric array

```
[46,70,34]
```

How can I filter query selecting only those rows where present let's say '70' in a JSON field? Something similar to JSON_CONTAINS in MySQL.

I have already tried

```
SELECT id, name, IN(tags, '70') AS c FROM index WHERE c = 1;
```

and

```
SELECT id, name, ALL(var='70' FOR var IN tags) as c FROM index WHERE c=1;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully think...

```
SELECT id, name FROM index WHERE tags = 70;
```

should just work. JSON arrays, end up working 'like' a MVA.

Otherwise, you would want `ANY()` (not `ALL()`), because only **one** of the values in the JSON array would be 70, not all of them (46 wouldn't match for example!)

```
SELECT id, name, ANY(var=70 FOR var IN tags) as c FROM index WHERE c=1;
```

(finally as a numeric value, shouldn't be quoted!)